# getting the values from function call and using them in function in python

Tags: python

```
def fun(EACH) : 
   list1 = []
   EACH = str(EACH)
    for all in a:  # contains names of different checks     
        for files in b :
              for line in open(str(files)) : 
                 if EACH in line :
                           print files
                           break
```

Here `a` is a directory which contains many files. I'm storing those files in list `b`.
I want to extract files with names in `EACH`

E.g. I want to open file which as a string "apple" in its content. this apple word is passed via arguments.

The problem is that I don't understand how to read that value and use the same string in the `if` condition.

Comment: what are `a` and `b`, and why is `a` even there, you don't seem to be using it for anything?

Comment: Please fix your indentation to match your actual code. This won't run at all.

Comment: a is a directory , i copied just a part of my code.. a is a list which is used to store the directory path and b is used to hold the all the files in that directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have to parse each file line by line ? Couldn't you just do something like :

```
for b in a:
    for fname in b:
        with open(fname, "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
        if EACH in content:
            print "There's a {0} in {1}".format(EACH, fname)
```

(the `with open(...) as ...` is to make sure your file is closed once you've read it...)

Comment: the issue is im not able to read EACH from arguments.. even ur code have to read EACH from the arguments that were passed to the function. how to use that argument and how to use that argument in if condition

Comment: OK, what us your function? What are its arguments? Why can't you read them? Please update your question.

Comment: its a small error and now it was resolved. thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
def grepFileForLines( self, fileName = "", keepLinesWith = "" ):
    file = open( fileName, 'r' )
    matches = []

    for line in file:
        if line.find( keepLinesWith ) > -1:
            matches.append( line )
    return matches
```

Comment: This won't work unless its in a class, `file` should not be used as a variable name; and you never close the file after you open it. You can replace `line.find(keepLinesWith)` with `if keepLineswith in line:` also see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Did you just copy your own code without even looking at the question  and the original code? And btw, there should be no spaces around parentheses. So instead of `grepFileForLines( self, fileName = "", keepLinesWith = "" )` it should be `grepFileForLines(self, fileName="", keepLinesWith="")`. Please study pep8 very carefully!